# AngularJS and option change text

Tags: angularjs, text, angular-ngselect

I have a select lists with currencies. Its made like this:

```
<select ng-model="model.currency">
    <option value="USD">Amercian Dollars</option>
    <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
</select>
```

I need to find a way so that the option text changes when I select an option. I tried an ng-change but I cant find a way to set the option text. Just to clarify:

1. The value should be the currency code
2. The selected text shown should be the currency code
3. If I click on my select the list of options should be the fullname

So whats missing in the scenario above is to set the value as text when selecting it.

Answer (score 1):

[`select`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) is a special directive in AngularJS. You need to declare ng-options and set options in controller.

Comment: yepp, I done that in other places, but still I dont know how to display the value when selected and the text when the select is active (eg. clicked)

Comment: create jsFiddle with issue and I will show you how to solve it.

Comment: When I select American dollars I want the selected option in the select to say USD. When I select Euro I want the selected option to say EUR (eg. replace American dollars to USD and Euro to EUR when I select it. I only want the full name in the list, but short name to display when selected)

Comment: so do it, what are u waiting for? I'm not your employee, go learn by example and do what u need.